# How to convert my given string to date format?

Tags: java, json, java-8

I have JsonObject in this dob key contain date format but i don't want this format how I convert it...

```
String dobDate=String.valueOf(gridData.get("DOB"));
```

it returning string is: `2006-12-31T18:30:00.000Z`

But I want to convert this date to `"dd-MM-yyyy"`
how I can d this.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat f= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String date = f.format(dobDate);
System.out.println(date);

Comment: its better to use `Instant instant = Instant.parse("2006-12-31T18:30:00.000Z");` from [**java.time**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Comment: In which time zone do you want the date? If you’re in India, for example, you string is equal to 2007-01-01T00:00 local time. It is never the same date everywhere on earth.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure this question is a duplicate!

But here is the answer:

This uses the old way with the `Date` object

```
SimpleDateFormat format  = new SimpleStringFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.zzZ");
Date d = format.parse("Your date String return thing");
```

Then you have a `Date` Object,
 (I am not completely sure if the pattern is right)
If you need it as String:

```
To get a String out of it use:
String newDateFormat = format.format(d);
```

The way above is working. If you interested in doing it in a "modern" way,

take a look at this classes:

- [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/time/Instant.html)
- [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)
- [GregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) and
- [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

I think time handling is a complex topic and you should investigate a bit if you work with it!

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` are hardly modern, even though they did try to solve some of the design problems in `Date`. In any case, java.time has fully replaced them. `Instant` and `LocalDate` that you mention are the recommended classes to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you have java.util.Date you can use this

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String formatted = df.format(gridData.get("DOB"));
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: when i using this it not working as accepted  Date dobDate=sdf.parse(String.valueOf(gridData.get("DOB")));
            String dobMap=sdf.format(dobDate);

Comment: you used the wrong pattern

Comment: its more like this yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.zzZ
I dont know if it is valid but it seems to be a more suitable solution